# Why can't I select text as an obstacle for a fluid simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have created a domain and have created an inflow. I want the fluid to hit some text, however when I select the text there is no option available to make it an obstacle for the fluid. Please help.

Comment: Is your text a mesh object? convert it to a mesh with Alt + C and see if it works

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution for me. Please post this as answer, maybe Pollard will see it and accept it!